# How to return multiple numbers in an array, in a single print statement

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.ArrayList<StudentDataArray> info = new java.util.ArrayList<StudentDataArray>();
    int amountOfPeople = KeyboardInput.promptForInt("Enter how many people you plan to enter into the list.");
    for(int a=0;a<amountOfPeople;a++) {
        try {
        double[] grade = new double[5];
        grade[0]=KeyboardInput.promptForDouble("Enter the First grade");
        grade[1]=KeyboardInput.promptForDouble("Enter the Second grade");
        grade[2]=KeyboardInput.promptForDouble("Enter the Third grade");
        grade[3]=KeyboardInput.promptForDouble("Enter the Fourth grade");
        grade[4]=KeyboardInput.promptForDouble("Enter the Fifth grade");
            info.add(new StudentDataArray(KeyboardInput.promptForString("Enter the First Name"),KeyboardInput.promptForString("Enter the Last Name"),grade,KeyboardInput.promptForChar("Enter the Final Grade")));
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("Hello World :)");
        }
    }
    for(int b=0;b<amountOfPeople;b++) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-3f %-3s",info.get(b).getFN(),info.get(b).getLN(),info.get(b).getTS(),info.get(b).getFG());
    }
}
}

public class StudentDataArray {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double[] testScore;
private char finalGrade;
public StudentDataArray(String FN, String LN, double[] TS, char FG) {
    firstName = FN;
    lastName = LN;
    testScore = TS;
    finalGrade = FG;
}
public void setFN(String FN) {firstName = FN;};
public void setLN(String LN) {lastName = LN;}
public void setTS(double[] TS) {testScore = TS;}
public void setFG(char FG) {finalGrade = FG;}
public String getFN() {return firstName;};
public String getLN() {return lastName;}
public String getTS() {
    for(int a=0;a<testScore.length;a++) {
        return testScore[a]+"   ";
    }
    return null;
}
public char getFG() {return finalGrade;}
}
```

Hey guys, this is my code for all to look at. What im trying to do is to return multiple doubles into one spot in the code. what it will look like is...

Ethan Michael       10  20  30  40  50     A

where this is all displayed in one statement
[10  20  30  40  50]

Since I am using a double[] i wasnt sure how to go about this.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of answers but none use a `StringBuilder`, which is recommended instead of concatenation in loops. It doesn't create a new String object in each iteration, so it is a lot easier on resources. As such:

```
public String getTS() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int a=0;a<testScore.length;a++) {
        sb.append(testScore[a]+" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I like this idea the most because when i program i try (to the best of my knowledge) to create efficient code for my programs. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for statement to concatenate all the info into one variable and then print it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in one neat line:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(testScores).replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", "");
```

You can use this expession (ie everything to the right of the equals dign) in-line wherever you need the string.

The key points of this are to use [`Arrays.toString()][1]`, which produces a string like `"[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]"`, then calling [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to strip out all the punctuation.

Comment: Upvoted for being an interesting, non-obvious solution. Probably not the most efficient way to go, but it's cool nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would need something like this:

```
public String getTS() {
    returnString := "";
    for(int a=0;a<testScore.length;a++) {
        returnString += testScore[a]+"   ";
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getTS() {
yourString:= "";
for(int a=0;a<testScore.length;a++) {
        yourString+= testScore[a]+"   ";
    }
  return ts;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing would be to convert `GetTS()` to something like this:

```
public String getTS() {
    String ts = "";
    for(int a=0;a<testScore.length;a++) {
        ts += testScore[a]+"   ";
    }
    return ts;
}
```

Note that your format string in Main.java should then change to `"%-10s %-10s %-3s %-3s"`.